# Spurious Enter ParameterValue message

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with an unbound Short Date field called StartDate and a click button to initiate VBA Code as follows and I get the 'Enter Parameter Message' for StartDate. StockTakeDate is also a short date field. Any advice on getting rid of the message would be welcome.

```
Private Sub cmdInventory_Click()

    strMsg = "Enter StartDate as Today's date or later"

    If Me.[StartDate] < Date Then 
        MsgBox strMsg, ExitSub 
    Else
        Dim strSQL
        strSQL = " UPDATE [Inventory] " _
            & " SET [Inventory].[InStock] = [Inventory].[StockTake] " _
            & " WHERE ([Inventory].[StockTakeDate] >= Me.[StartDate]) "
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Me.SomeField` when using `DoCmd.RunSQL`. Instead, use `Forms!SomeForm!SomeField`:

```
Dim strSQL
strSQL = " UPDATE [Inventory] " _
         & " SET [Inventory].[InStock] = [Inventory].[StockTake] " _
         & " WHERE ([Inventory].[StockTakeDate] >= Forms!MyFormName![StartDate]) "
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Thank you. For a first timer VBA is somewhat confusing. I will test it.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the parameter value (StartDate) formatted as a string expression:

```
strSQL = " UPDATE [Inventory] " _
    & " SET [Inventory].[InStock] = [Inventory].[StockTake] " _
    & " WHERE ([Inventory].[StockTakeDate] >= #" & Format(Me![StartDate].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Thank you will test it.